# jQuery append() div tag not working as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, append

i'm having a problem with my append div.
here is a rough idea of my html

```
<table>
<tr>
<td>title 1</td>
<td>subject 2</td>
</tr>
<div id='appenddiv'></div>
<tr>
<td>title 2</td>
<td>subject 2</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

and my jquery script is this:

```
var output = "<tr><td>title added</td><td>subject added</td></tr>";
$('#appenddiv').append(htmloutput);
```

All works fine with the script and it fires when it should etc.. but my problem is, instead of placing the new html inside the div tags, it just adds it to the top of the table?

any idea why?

Comment: Typo right? $('#appenddiv').append(htmloutput);

Comment: Your HTML is invalid.

Comment: How can you put a div like this?

Answer (score 3):

As moonwave99 said, you can't have a `<div>` as a direct child of your table element. If you always to add after the first row, you can do:

```
var output = "<tr><td>title added</td><td>subject added</td></tr>";
$('table tr:first').after(output);
```

Comment: ok thanks, is it possible to have table tr:second and so on also or is it only first?

Comment: Unfortunately it is only for `first` and `last`. Giving classes to each `tr` will probably help if you plan on modifying this table a lot.

Comment: yeah, that didnt work because it just screwed up my outer tables by placing it inside that instead. I think i'm going to have to do it with id assign

Answer (score 1):

You can't have a `<div>` as a direct child of a `<table>` element, so it's rendered outside of it.

Answer (score 0):

Your html structure is not valid. You shouldn't place a `div` between `tr's`. You should place it inside a `td` if you want it inside your table.

If you want to add another row to your table, you should place a `tr` instead of your `div` element, and append it's content, or you should use jQuery `.after()` or `.before()` to position your element at a specific position.

Answer (score 0):

you can only append div inside a `<td>` if you want to have a div in a table otherwise you cannot just add `<div>` inside `<table>`

Answer (score 0):

I think no need to assign a variable, you can put html code directly to after() method.

Below is the script:

```
$('table tr:first').after("<tr><td>title added</td><td>subject added</td></tr>");
```

Above script will always add new row after the first row.